# Amnesia: the dark descent not installing

Tags: package-management

I've tried 3 times now to install amnesia from USC, but every time I do, it gives an error and the code below.

```
installArchives() failed: (Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 186914 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking amnesia (from .../amnesia_1.2.1-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/amnesia_1.2.1-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--       unpack):
failed in write on buffer copy for backend dpkg-deb during    `./opt/amnesia/maps/main/ch01/05_wine_cellar.map': No space left on device
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/amnesia_1.2.1-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
Error in function: 
SystemError: E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Has anyone else experienced this? can I fix it?

Comment: Is your partition full by any chance?

Comment: 89% used. Might have to switch some over from vista.

Comment: "Available 3.6G" in the info it says 2.5G expanded. This should work.

Comment: Please edit your post to include the full output of `df -h`

Answer (score 0):

> failed in write on buffer copy for backend dpkg-deb during    `./opt/amnesia/maps/main/ch01/05_wine_cellar.map': No space left on device

This is a clue to what's going on, you're out of disk space.